# How to map all interaction models of RSocket in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rsocket

There are 4 interaction models provided in RSocket.

- fire and forget
- request and response
- request stream
- request channel
- (metadata push)

Spring(and Spring Boot) provides RSocket integration, it is easy to build a RSocket server with the existing messaging infrastructure to hide the original RSocket APIs.

```java
   @MessageMapping("hello")
    public Mono<Void> hello(Greeting p) {
        log.info("received: {} at {}", p, Instant.now());
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    @MessageMapping("greet.{name}")
    public Mono<String> greet(@DestinationVariable String name, @Payload Greeting p) {
        log.info("received: {}, {} at {}", name, p, Instant.now());
        return Mono.just("Hello " + name + ", " + p.getMessage() + " at " + Instant.now());
    }

    @MessageMapping("greet-stream")
    public Flux<String> greetStream(@Payload Greeting p) {
        log.info("received:  {} at {}", p, Instant.now());
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map(i -> "Hello #" + i + "," + p.getMessage() + " at " + Instant.now());
    }
```

And in the client side, there is a `RescoketRequester` provided to shake hands with the server.

```
    @GetMapping("hello")
    Mono<Void> hello() {
        return this.requester.route("hello").data(new Greeting("Welcome to Rsocket")).send();
    }

    @GetMapping("name/{name}")
    Mono<String> greet(@PathVariable String name) {
        return this.requester.route("greet." + name).data(new Greeting("Welcome to Rsocket")).retrieveMono(String.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    Flux<String> greetStream() {
        return this.requester.route("greet-stream").data(new Greeting("Welcome to Rsocket"))
                .retrieveFlux(String.class)
                .doOnNext(msg -> log.info("received messages::" + msg));
    }
```

But how to use <del>**requestChannel** and</del> **metadataPush** model in Spring way(using messaging infrastructure)?

The sample codes is on [Github](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample). **Update**: added **requestChannel** sample.

**Update**: **SETUP** and **METADATA_PUSH** can be handled by `@ConnectMapping`. And Spring Security RSocket can secure **SETUP** and **REQUEST**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reference example

For a reference example, let's refer to the client-to-server integration tests and, in particular, to the `ServerController` class: [spring-framework/RSocketClientToServerIntegrationTests.java (line 200) at 6d7bf8050fe710c5253e6032233021d5e025e1d5 · spring-projects/spring-framework · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6d7bf8050fe710c5253e6032233021d5e025e1d5/spring-messaging/src/test/java/org/springframework/messaging/rsocket/RSocketClientToServerIntegrationTests.java#L200).

This commit has been mentioned in the release notes:

> <…>
>
> - [RSocket](http://rsocket.io/) support including [response handling](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6d7bf8050fe710c5253e6032233021d5e025e1d5/spring-messaging/src/test/java/org/springframework/messaging/rsocket/RSocketClientToServerIntegrationTests.java#L200) via annotated `@MessageMapping` methods and [performing requests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6d7bf8050fe710c5253e6032233021d5e025e1d5/spring-messaging/src/test/java/org/springframework/messaging/rsocket/RSocketClientToServerIntegrationTests.java#L151) via `RSocketRequester`.
>
> <…>
>
> — [Spring Framework 5.2.0.M1 available now](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/10/spring-framework-5-2-0-m1-available-now).

## Channel interaction model

The corresponding code part of the reference example:

```java
@MessageMapping("echo-channel")
Flux<String> echoChannel(Flux<String> payloads) {
    return payloads.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(10)).map(payload -> payload + " async");
}
```

## Metadata push

It seems that, currently, it is not supported by the `@MessageMapping` annotation.